# Symfony - Read-only entities hydrated from YAML

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

Is it possible to have simple read-only entities, that can have an association with an other doctrine entity, but their data is stored in a text ( YAML ) file ?

Let's say I have a `product` entity, and I want to set a category for each product. But for now, I only have very few categories ( and don't need to edit or add ), so I don't want/need to create a full doctrine entity with it's own table in the DB.

So I create a very simple entity:

```
class ProductCategory
{

    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

Now I would like to create a simple YAML file where the data is stored, like so:

```
0: Cheese
1: Meat
2: Dairy Products
....
```

Then I would like to set a ManyToOne relation from the `product` entity to the `ProductCategory` entity.

Is that possible ?
And, how to "query" the categories ? ( let's say I want to list all categories that start with a certain letter )

'Why' you ask ?
Well for now, as I said, I only have very few categories, but maybe some day I want to add many more, and even have a CRUD editor for them and so on, then I could easily convert it to a full doctrine entity.

Or any other suggestions on how to approach this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a library that provides what you are looking for that's called Alice:

- https://github.com/nelmio/alice
- https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle
- https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker
- https://github.com/h4cc/AliceFixturesBundle

This way you can create random test data en masse and can still work with Doctrine as usual.

If you want to do this manually it will be a pain to solve the problem of connecting the entities. Your best bet is to keep all of them in arrays with id's being used as keys but even then you will probably end up writing lots of glue code to connect the entities.

Comment: This looks like a lot of effort and overhead. I thought there was an easier way. I think I will go with a standard doctrine entity.
But THANK YOU for your answer !

Comment: Another possibility would be to use the Doctrine FixturesBundle: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle It will require you to set up entities but might be a bit more convenient than doing all of the setup yourself. You can find some examples in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this fixture idea ... first, fixtures are only meant for testing, right ? Second, fixtures still need a table in the DB, so no gain here. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Fixtures are primarily for testing, but not only. For example you could want to initialize your app with demo data in some cases or maybe you always want to provide a set of initial data, like JIRA comes with an already prepared simple workflow and generic issue types. So what you use them for is up to you.
Yes, you will still need the database, but it might ease the burden of setting up your initial data (each time), as it seemed like this is what you wanted to avoid. It could very well be that this won't solve your problem, but I figured it might be helpful.

Comment: And I appreciate ... but this indeed not was I was looking for.